# ExternalLoginConfirmation returns user already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

I have a really bizarre situation that I do not understand.

1. I have an MVC Web app with Google and Facebook authentication. After user is authenticated it is redirected to `ExternalLoginCallback` action for registration.
2. after entering email address - user is registered in the system using `ExternalLoginConfirmation` action:

   ```
       if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
       }

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
           var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
           if (info == null)
           {
               return View("ExternalLoginFailure", "_UnauthorizedLayout");
           }

           var firstName = GetUserClaim(info, ClaimTypes.GivenName);
           var lastName = GetUserClaim(info, ClaimTypes.Surname);

           var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email,
                                            FirstName = firstName,
                                            LastName = lastName,
                                            Email = model.Email };

           var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
           if (result.Succeeded)
           {
               // add login
               result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
               if (result.Succeeded)
               {
                   result = await AddUserClaims(user, info);
                   if (result.Succeeded)
                   {
                       await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                       return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                   }
               }
           }
           AddErrors(result);
       }

       ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
       return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "_UnauthorizedLayout", model);
   ```

This is all pretty standard.

Problem is that some users report they try to register after they have authenticated using facebook/google and they get an error saying the user already exists. This is for sure not true as they have tried with multiple emails that have never been registered.

I didn't manage to reproduce this on my computer. I could only assume problem is in this line

`var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);`

returning user exists error. I am 100% positive the user is not already registered. I guess there is some sort of race condition here or something. No idea really.

Any help would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why this is happening but I ended up using a check to see if the user is already registered, and if he is log him in instead.